# touch mouseOver in createjs - DispatchEvent() not working in iPhone/iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html5, easeljs

I have recently developed an html5 game using createjs and I am currently in the testing phase. The game seems to work fine in all the devices except for the iPhone. After careful analysis I have come to a conclusion that the dispatchevent(), I'm employing in the code to run the createjs built-in rollover() function which I'm dispatching using the dispatchevent() isn't working in the IOS.Apart from this the game seems to be doing all the other tasks in the ios just fine. But since this is the main functionality I'm kind of stuck. The following is the code snipet where I'm employing the dispatchevent() :

```
                    if(tile[i][j].name != 4)
                      tile[i][j].addEventListener("click",onTileClick);

                      tile[i][j].defined = true;
                      tile[i][j].tweened = false;
                      tile[i][j].cursor = "pointer";

                      tile[i][j].on("rollover",onTileOver);
                      tile[i][j].on("pressmove", function(evt){
                        var o = stage.getObjectUnderPoint(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
                        console.log("GET", o, evt.stageX, evt.stageY);

                          o.dispatchEvent("rollover");

                      });
                      tile[i][j].addEventListener("rollout",onTileOut);
                      stage.addChild(tileBg[i][j],tile[i][j]);
```

Any suggestions in this regard?